How could Saturn become an economically attractive site for space tourism?
So, the way I see it Saturn seems to be an extremely good future space tourist attraction from a marketing perspective:

It has Titan, with its methane lakes and seas and even the potential to fly under wing power.
It has Enceladus’s impressive geysers and Iapetus which is the only moon to have a black and white coloration that we know of.
All of this is under a relatively low radiation environment, as opposed to Jupiter.
Saturn itself would be magnificent from any of the moons. A polar hexagon and… of course… the ring system.

However, there is one huge problem: sheer distance. Saturn is twice as far as Jupiter from Earth on average, a daunting challenge with nuclear or even non-torchship fusion drives. I am trying to figure out if there would still be an economically viable case in a moderately developed solar system (colonies on Moon, Mars and some supply depots/robotic stations further out).
What are the necessary technological or societal requirements for space tourism to Saturn to become economically viable?
P.S. this question was inspired by this amazing poster from NASA.

You are asking 2 different questions. Pick one, please

OK, edited to clarify the title question.

"What are the necessary [...] requirements for [...] tourism to  to become economically viable?" Affordable and fast travel, affordable and comfortable accomodations, marketable attractions, and a great night life?

Well, for one: cheap, ultra-efficient, high-thrust engines... completely economically infeasible with current tech. With a torch drive you could go pretty much anywhere pretty trivially, so either you have that or you need to add more details about tech you have in this world to the question.

VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help], which is a fancy way of saying, "this doesn't conform to the rules." The question is broad (book rule), open-ended, asks two markedly different questions (tech vs. society) and doesn't define what it means to be "economically viable" (Amtrak is subsidized by the government but causes billions in economic benefits to the locations it covers, so it's viable in one point of view and not in another). Finally, without an explanation as to how a best answer will be judged, this is just brainstorming, which is a no-go.

VTC:Not About Worldbuilding not because of the reasons JBH brought up, because this site is supposed to be for authors who are trying to solve problems with their setting.  If you are just curious about it, but don't have an actual project of some sort to help you with, then this is not the right site for that.

We've added a chatroom to hopefully help work on some questions that don't fit the usual model particularly well, if you want some further input head over to Story Tellers Corner with your question and we'll see if we can help.

Frame Challenge
The viability is a function of its exclusivity.
Space Tourism or Oceangate (before that business... imploded) had ridiculously high price points and yet there were people willing to pay that money to do something that not only on its own merits is really freaking cool...
but more importantly is something that few other people have done
And for a certain sector of society who has enough money to do anything and everything, the value is in doing something that the eponymous Joneses have not done.
If it costs several million per ticket, or even tens of millions per ticket:
there are people that would pay that to one-up there fellow socialites

"imploded" jeez, on the nose, are we? ;) (+1) I agree that the expenses of private spaceflight would make it a socialite/elite destination only.

It was too good of a pun to pass up...

Frame challenge

Economically

This alone can't be satisfied, as the expenses of maintaining a something that should house humans on Saturn's orbit is already prohibitively expensive, even for a more advanced civilization with colonies on Mars. And, while Enceladus and Iapetus might be good views from a mere flyby, you'll have to land on Titan to offer your clients a "fly under your own power" attraction. This adds some serious value to the required delta-V, which is already large. Don't forget the cold.

Attractive

For an attractive tourist site, you require local service and a variety of activities available there. For all of these, you need people. With such expensive transfer as you have already described, you need people to live there, that is, they aren't seasoned workers, they are inhabitants of some space points en route and on Saturn's moons. But for all of them, you need food, water, power and air - mind you, you're not on Earth where you might get local supply, you're 8x farther from the Sun with 1/64x the insolation and power generation. (Yes you might get some watts off Saturn's radiation, but it'll be a drop in the sea) So, all of this should be shipped from elsewhere, increasing the total cost of the touristic mission.

Tourism

And for the site to be available for tourism, it's required that one can reach that site and back in a reasonable amount of time. You declare your civ has got torch-ships, still even with a torch-ship it'll take a good 6 months to reach there, all the time being pretty much locked in a crude cell with only the required service (worse than economy class flight, or a public train, for way longer). And not even an elite could be locked out of their company's life for that long, including actual delay of interactions (a tad more than two hours a roundtrip request, no way to say hold a verbal conversation), so whoever desires to at last sustain his position in the world will not embark on such an endeavor. Also at these lengths the missions to Titan would not be even close to tourism, instead they'll be like medieval era exploration missions, with months amidst the ocean, left to the grace of winds and storms with little hope of seeing more land. I really doubt that a man rich enough would take on such an adventure.
So, no "economical", no "attractive", no "tourism" is available at this distance.

Capital of the Solar System!
Saturn has gravity comparable to Earth and abundant access to all the CHON elements so important for biochemistry.  We'll assume space commerce in trace elements and some degree of genetic revision of spacebound life to rely less on rarer elements like phosphorus (yes, that means using something like PNA for genetic material).  Then we note that Saturn has the area of 83 Earths.  You learn how to tap the energy of its immense atmospheric turbulence to keep platforms safely aloft, and establish a civilized means of pushing one against another to have fine control over how they all move.  The result is that you have effectively hundreds of thousands times more surface area than Earth, atop fantasy islands of graphene lit by the power of the winds fueled by Saturn's boundless internal heat.  Did I mention the temperature at around 20 atm depth is the same as Earth's? Once you engineer a bit of flamingo-leg magic into your colonists, even the smell outside doesn't bother them, though they'll still need a new metabolic system powered by electricity, rigged to convey electrons away from their mitochondria, to get around the lack of free oxygen.
The biggest draw of Saturn is that the islands are ever-moving: once you've set up residence anywhere, you have fairly predictable periodic access to hundreds of Earths' worth of communities.  Anything, anything you can imagine, there is a place for.  People come to see the communities they've always dreamed of; but due to the immense affluence of the tiny historic communities of Earth, they still go home in the end.
